# containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error: (null)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, watchos-2, healthkit

Trying to authorize on watchOS. Getting this error:

2019-03-20 18:32:45.859857-0600 iRun WatchKit Extension[21129:1854743] [default] containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error: (null)

My Capabilities for both my App and my Watch Extension are both turned on for HealthKit.

There is a similar question to mine on here but no one has answered it. Can't find any way to interpret this error??

My code to authorize:

```
  if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {

            let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
            let heartRateQuantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!
            let allTypes = Set([HKObjectType.workoutType(),
                                heartRateQuantityType
                ])

            healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: nil, read: allTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
                if success == false {
                    print("Error")
                }
        }
        }
```

And for the AppDelegate.swift in my app:

```
func applicationShouldRequestHealthAuthorization(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
        healthStore.handleAuthorizationForExtension { (success, error) -> Void in

        }
    }
```

Comment: I also have ran into this issue. I filed a tech support question with Apple and never heard back. It seems to be random for me. Is it random for you as well? Also does this happen on your device or simulator?